# Accidentally overwrote a file

Tags: windows-10, python, restore

I accidentally overwrote an existing dataset file using the following Python command.

```
pickle.load(open('mydata.pickle', 'wb'))
```

I intended to load the data, but mistakenly used 'wb' option instead of 'rb'.

Is there any way I can restore the original contents of this file?
The above file name exists in the original folder with file size 0.

The OS is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can restore the original contents of this file? The
> above file name exists in the original folder with file size 0.

Quite possibly not.

**(1)** Try restoring to an earlier point See if you see the file that way.

**(2)** Consider recovery programs like Recuva or Easus  .

Be aware the it is possible for recovery products like this to make changes to the disk that damages further recovery attempts.

**(3)** If no backup and recovery is a priority, first contact a local recovery agency and see if they can help